# Reference for Generalized Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for references on generalized eigenvectors and Jordan matrix representation. I would like a brief but complete introduction of this concepts with a nice treatment of the most important properties. I'm studying automorphisms of the torus and many proofs requiere good knowledge on this topics (for example regarding properties that relate the spectral radius matrix with contraction properties). Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler or Linear Algebra and its Applications by Lax come to mind.  I'm sure there are others.

Comment: You are probably looking for a reference book. Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson might help.